# Not able to execute the Create table sql query through java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to *create the table through java string but it is displaying error as table doesn't exist* but when I run the same query directly on workbench it runs fine. Below is my code

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" ;
String dbname = "tweetmap";
String username = "root";
String password = "root";
try
{ 
    // SQL Driver needed for connecting to Database
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbname,username,password);
    c.setAutoCommit(true);
    stmt = c.createStatement();

    //Creating the Database if not Already Present
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists senti "
            + "( latitude double NULL, "
            + "longitude double NULL, "
            +  "Sentiment TEXT  NULL) ";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    if(sentiment != null){

        stmt1 = c.createStatement();    
        stmt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `senti`(latitude,longitude,Sentiment) VALUE ('"+lati+"','"+longi+"','"+sentiment+"')");
        }
    }
catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I think it's bcoz u haven't specify `primary key` for the table & `remove IF NOT EXISTS` clause from the query. Try the same.

Comment: Please refer below link. May that help you. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm

Comment: I have written according to this tutorial only, the thing is that when I run my query directly on workbench it works fine and there is no atrribute in my table that requires primary key

Comment: Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016363/java-creating-tables-in-mysql-database

Comment: Though this is not answer, but creating table from java is bad practice. May I know reason why you want to do this ? As far I know, it is better to use DML only from java.

Comment: if that the case then I will create the table directly in MySQL only as I have used this thing earlier but haven't came up with this type of exception

Comment: Try using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename` & then use `CREATE TABLE tablename` command. May ur app tries to delete table which doesn't exists.

Comment: @esahmo is it working fine now ????

Comment: I tried to execute your code and it works fine for me try to print `Exception`

Answer (score 5):

this is the problem **stmt.executeUpdate(sql);**

instead of executeUpdate use **execute(String SQL**) method.

**execute(String SQL)** is used for **DDL/DML** statement
while **executeUpdate(String SQL)** is used only for **DML** operation

Answer (score 0):

Best way to execute any query in JDBC is using execute() method. This method can be used for any kind of query.
I hope below link will help you to understand more.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)